# cookies no se cargan en una página concreta

Tags: php

Me está ocurriendo al entrar en una página concreta, que las cookies no se cargan.

Las creo mediante PHP de la siguiente forma:

```
setcookie('idioma_', 'es', time() + (86400 * 365), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
```

Cuando entro a esa página que me falla, las cookies ya están creadas, si es algo que se guarda en el ordenador, no le veo ningún sentido a que no se carguen. Además, me re-establece los valores.

He analizado todas las páginas, mostrando los de la cookie en todo momento, y sólo me pasa con esta página en cuestión. Estoy trabajando en local, no sé si eso puede influir, y ocurre tanto en Chrome como en Firefox.

Comment: Tenia ese problema en uno de mis proyectos y llegue a la solución determinando que estaba intentado acceder a la cookie desde un directorio superior, osea que si la creaba en una carpeta inferior a la raíz no podía acceder a ella mediante el archivo index.php (por poner un ejemplo)

Comment: @YoAlbert Curioso, no conocía ese problema. El caso es que en mi caso están todas al mismo nivel (donde se crean me refiero). De hecho, este problema lo he encontrado hace unas horas en otra página, pero que al ser parecida a otra, donde sí me funcionaba la cookie, he cogido el código, lo he pegado, y no me ha vuelto a dar problema. Pero en este caso es una página totalmente distinta.

Comment: Has intentado setearla sin el último parámetro? que te de vuelve_ ***setcookie('idioma_', 'es', time() + (86400 * 365));***

Comment: El “/“ es para que la cookie esté disponible en todo el dominio.